# How to concatenate a variable to a string in smarty?

Tags: string, variables, smarty, concatenation, string-concatenation

I've following smarty code:

```
{foreach from=$preview_data key=key item=value}
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="units_$key" id="units_$key" value="{$value.units}">
{/foreach}
```

I want to attach a string **units_** to  a value contained in variable `$key`. I tried above code but it didn't work. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$key is just a variable, use the same syntax:

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="units_{$key}" id="units_{$key}" value="{$value.units}">
```